# Botpress whatsapp field extraction

Tags: whatsapp, arabic, translate, botpress

I have a chatbot built using the botpress cloud, there are two types of user employee and tenant, also the user can select english or arabic as the language, this chatbot is integrated with whatsapp, the arabic language is working fine with the tenant flow on both whatsapp and botpress emulator but the employee flow is working fine on botpress emulator not on the whatsapp when select any option it is just repeating the same question and here is my log from botpress. I tried to change the option text same as what tenant has for that also it is not working.

```
Actions Phone Number>> 94770048000
Actions :: Data >> { type: 'E', name: 'shafnaz', id: 15 }
Actions Registered Employee
Dialog [6b03846d-9bc5-4e8d-8b2c-dcf6733484c2] Execute transition "workflow.isEmployee"
Dialog [6b03846d-9bc5-4e8d-8b2c-dcf6733484c2] Transition from (flow:Main) [node:Welcome-FirstNode] to [node:ToEmployeeNode]
Dialog [6b03846d-9bc5-4e8d-8b2c-dcf6733484c2] Entering workflow (flow:Old Employee Workflow) [node:Entry] from (flow:Main) [node:ToEmployeeNode]
Dialog [6b03846d-9bc5-4e8d-8b2c-dcf6733484c2] Transition from (flow:Old Employee Workflow) [node:Entry] to [node:Standard]
DM [Capture] Start information capture
Dialog [6b03846d-9bc5-4e8d-8b2c-dcf6733484c2] Sending Message. Type: choice. Text: hey shafnaz! How can I help you?
Dialog [6b03846d-9bc5-4e8d-8b2c-dcf6733484c2] Waiting for user input
DM Executing hook conversation_turn_before_reply of agent "TranslatorAgent"
Hooks Translating 1 messages
Hooks Translated messages successfully
DM Executing hook conversation_turn_started of agent "TranslatorAgent"
DM [Capture] Transformed the extracted value
DM [Capture] The extracted answer is 'null'. The user probably didn't answer the question.
DM [Capture] Field extraction failed. Input: عرض الطلبات المعلقة
DM [Capture] Extraction failed (0/2 attempts)
DM [Capture] Retrying prompt
Dialog [6b03846d-9bc5-4e8d-8b2c-dcf6733484c2] Sending Message. Type: choice. Text: hey shafnaz! How can I help you?
Dialog [6b03846d-9bc5-4e8d-8b2c-dcf6733484c2] Waiting for user input
DM Executing hook conversation_turn_before_reply of agent "TranslatorAgent"
Hooks Translating 1 messages
Hooks Translated messages successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have the same issue. When user selects a Single Choice from dropdown in Whatsapp it does nothing. On the logs the extract does not happen.

However post selecting, If I type in the option manually , the flow continues as expected.

This is happening with single choice where the options are more than 3-4 which results in a drop down in whatsapp